# Sign of a continuous function has at most countably infinite discontinuties

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on some real interval $[a, b]$. Define $sign(f(x))$ to be equal to $1$ where $f(x) \geq 0$ and $-1$ everywhere else on $[a, b]$. Is the cardinality of set of points where $sign(f(x))$ is discontinuous at most countably infinite?

Comment: Hint: if $f(x) = -d_K(x)$, where $K$ is a closed set, then $f$ is continuous and $1 + \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sign}(f(x))$ is the indicator function of $K$.

Comment: By the way, $d_K(x) = \inf_{y \in K} |x - y|$.